# Compile x86_64 error(No such module error)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have done all the recommendation i found in the stack overflow

```
pod install
pod deintegrate
sudogem install cocoapods-clean
```

added arm64 in excluded architecture.
Still getting this error.

[image]

what to do?

Comment: Are you running the build on a real device or in a simulator?

Comment: Simulator @ShabnamSiddiqui

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `arm64` in excluded architecture of your project and target as well as in your pod target.

[image]

[image]